# remove all duplicate records

Tags: sql, t-sql

shows a lot of duplicates how can I remove them, I have tried to use distinct but the duplication still appears

```
SELECT fdp.PARENT_CASEID ,
fdp.POLICYNUMBER,
fdp.INSUREDNAME,
fdp.OWNERNAME,
fdp.AGENCYCODE,
fdpc.NIGO,
fdpc.NIGOREASON,
wci.WCSTATUS,
wci.DATECOMPLETED,
WCI.CREATEDDATETIME,
fdCI.NEWUNDERWRITINGUSER,
fdr.NBAMOUNT,
nr.NIGOREQUIREMENT,
d.MODIFIEDDATETIME[First Review]
FROM FDPolicyDetails fdp
INNER JOIN FDProcessing fdpc ON fdp.PARENT_CASEID = fdpc.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDWelcomeCall wci on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = wci.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDCaseInformation fdCI on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = FDCI.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDRounting fdr on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = FDR.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDNIGORequirements nr on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = NR.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN SONORADISCUSSIONS d on d.CASEFOLDERID = NR.PARENT_CASEID
;
```

Comment: Remember that SELECT DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: share sample data and output and your dbms name

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin dbms :Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` window function and can apply filter on that

```
with cte as
(SELECT fdp.PARENT_CASEID ,
fdp.POLICYNUMBER,
fdp.INSUREDNAME,
fdp.OWNERNAME,
fdp.AGENCYCODE,
fdpc.NIGO,
fdpc.NIGOREASON,
wci.WCSTATUS,
wci.DATECOMPLETED,
WCI.CREATEDDATETIME,
fdCI.NEWUNDERWRITINGUSER,
fdr.NBAMOUNT,
nr.NIGOREQUIREMENT,
d.MODIFIEDDATETIME,
row_number()over(partition by ---group of column order by column) rn
FROM FDPolicyDetails fdp
INNER JOIN FDProcessing fdpc ON fdp.PARENT_CASEID = fdpc.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDWelcomeCall wci on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = wci.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDCaseInformation fdCI on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = FDCI.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDRounting fdr on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = FDR.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN FDNIGORequirements nr on fdp.PARENT_CASEID = NR.PARENT_CASEID
JOIN SONORADISCUSSIONS d on d.CASEFOLDERID = NR.PARENT_CASEID
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: but how can I add this condition 
p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'PendingRequirements' or p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'FollowUpRequirements'

Comment: add filter inside cte